# How does Jenkins know tests history

Tags: jenkins

When a test fails Jenkins writes something like "Failing for the past 4 build (Since #12)". How does Jenkins know the test history - is it by string matching the class/test name to previous results? If the class name changes does it means that all history context for its tests is also lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, Jenkins seem to do string based matching of test names, so if a test does not run in a certain build for some reason, or is renamed, all history for this test is also lost (at least for the use case I mentioned)